# Aurora RDS is resetting primary keys

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

We recently tried to migrate our unit tests to Aurora from Mysql. We had to roll it back because some tests suddenly began to fail due to composite index collisions. We traced it back to the primary key of our users table, which is auto incrementing.

If a user is added to the users table, they are issued an auto-incrementing id. So if the user is added with id=7, we expect the next user to be added with id=8. This hasn't been the case. If we removed user 7, the next user is not always added with id=8. Rather, they are sometimes added with id=7 again, depending on when the user is added.

We ran a test to see how Aurora db handled primary keys and got strange results:

```
mysql> select max(id) from testtable;
```

```
+---------+
| max(id) |
+---------+
|      22 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
mysql> select * from testtable;
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | value1 |
|  2 | value2 |
|  4 | value4 |
|  6 | value5 |
|  7 | value6 |
|  8 | value7 |
| 22 | value8 |
+----+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete from testtable where id = 22;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)                                                                                                                                                                         
mysql> show table status where name = 'testtable';                                                                                                                                                          +-----------+--------+-----------------+

| Name      | Engine |  Auto_increment | 
+-----------+--------+-----------------+
| testtable | InnoDB |        23       | 
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Then, we waited 15 minutes and ran the same query

```
mysql> show table status where name = 'testtable';
+-----------+--------+-----------------+
| Name      | Engine |  Auto_increment | 
+-----------+--------+-----------------+
| testtable | InnoDB |   9             | 
+-----------+--------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

It appears that, after a certain amount of time since the Aurora db is idle, some event occurs that causes aurora to treat it as if a server restart has occurred, and it resets the auto increment value to MAX(id) + 1, which is the behaviour of an innodb table.

These seems insane to me, and certainly not something we would use in a production environment without there being incredibly catastrophic consequences, especially on a legacy database with a flawed db schema and bad foreign key relationship.

Has anyone run into this issue before? Is this just a case of a configuration setting?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html "In MySQL 5.7 and earlier, the auto-increment counter is stored only in main memory, not on disk. To initialize an auto-increment counter after a server restart, InnoDB would execute the equivalent of the following statement on the first insert into a table containing an AUTO_INCREMENT column: `SELECT MAX(ai_col) FROM table_name FOR UPDATE;`"

Comment: Chances are Aurora "restarts" regularly. It's auto-scaling, so as it grows/shrinks it's going to incur restarts.

Comment: Excellent response. This is the answer we were leaning toward, but didn't make the connection that auto-scaling represents a type of restart. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: MySQL 8.0 stores auto-inc counters persistently, so they aren't reset on a restart. Perhaps someday Aurora will fork MySQL 8.0 and support that behavior.